# In Groovy, how to get annotation values for parameters inside closures?

Tags: groovy

For example, given this groovy code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType
import java.lang.annotation.Target

@Target([ElementType.PARAMETER])
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Bar {
  String qux() default ""
}

def closure1 = { @Bar(qux = 'zxv') String foo ->
  println foo
}

println "[value for qux]"
```

How would you print the value for qux (which in this case is 'zxv') ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection API can give you what you're looking for (I'm using Groovy 2.5 on Java 8).

The closure is essentially a method named `call` on a [Closure](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html) instance, and `parameterAnnotations[0][0]` is a quick way of getting that [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)'s first parameter's first annotation.

```
def anno = closure1.class.methods.find { it.name == 'call' }.parameterAnnotations[0][0]
println anno.qux() // prints zxv
```